# How to make UC browser like settings-popup menu in bottom bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to build this UI for browser screen got stuck in one part for a long time and couldn't find any relevant topic on the web. I want to implement UC browser settings/hamburger menu that popup as dialog. How do I get started on this thing

[images link contain-2 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwv4I.jpg)

Just found one [link](https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/implementing-googles-refreshed-modal-bottom-sheet-4e76cb5de65b) somewhat loosely related to it. I am confused, Please help me out. I did implement the bottom navigation bar Just want that popup view/menu to appear

Comment: It's really simple bottom sheet dialog. You can make it static in xml or dynamic as a fragment, but it will look the same. Just put it in a CardView with rounded corners and add some margins so it will lift up from the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Dialog for achieve this type of layout:

**Try layout xml like below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/android_icon"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Android1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/android_icon"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Android1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/android_icon"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Android1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> Java

**Code in Activity**

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
 dialog.setCancelable(true);
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
 Window window = dialog.getWindow();
 WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
 wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
 window.setAttributes(wlp);
 window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 dialog.show();
```

> Kotlin

```
val dialog = Dialog(this@MainActivity)
        dialog.setCancelable(true)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog)
        val window = dialog.getWindow()
        val card_layout:CardView=dialog.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card_layout)
        var parameter:FrameLayout.LayoutParams = card_layout.getLayoutParams() as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
        parameter.setMargins(30,30,30,30) // left, top, right, bottom
        card_layout.setLayoutParams(parameter)
        val wlp = window.getAttributes()
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
        window.setAttributes(wlp)
        window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        dialog.show()
```

**Output for above code:**

[image]

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Ok this does work, but How do I set margin for this view coz setting gravity bottom does put it down to the screen, I want it bit up and I am working this on kotlin.

Comment: Set margin to your parent layout of dialog in xml file.

Comment: Thank you for converting the code in kotlin, Issue here is normally we set margin by getting a variable using this  `window as LayoutType.LayoutParams` , and using that variable we can set margins in run time, but here I cannot get at what thing do I achieve this. Since we are setting gravity in runtime, then I suppose it's viable to set margin in runtime.

Comment: Please try 
`var parameter:FrameLayout.LayoutParams = card_layout.getLayoutParams() as FrameLayout.LayoutParams`
        


`parameter.setMargins(30,30,30,30)`

Check edited answer.